# Программа не вычисляет среднее арифметическое двухмерного массива

Tags: c++

Есть три задачи которые нужно объединить в одну.
Только с использованием функций.

Напишите функцию, которая определяет двумерный массив целых чисел:

Сумма всех элементов в массиве;

Среднее арифметическое всех элементов в массиве;

Я изучаю C ++ и только начинаю разбираться в виртуальных функциях.

Для описанной задачи виртуальные функции  требуются. Обязательно должен быть 2D-массив.

Нельзя поместить код из  функций Sum и Average и поместить в main. Хочу разобраться с головной болью при передаче массивов и результатов.

Исправьте мои ошибки, пожалуйста

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FillRandomNumbers
(int** matrix, const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
    srand(time(0)); 

    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            matrix[row][column] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}


void Print(int** matrix, const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            cout << matrix[row][column] << " ";   
        }
    }
}


int Sum(int** matrix, const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            sum += matrix[row][column];
        }
    }
    return sum; 
}

int  Average(float average, size_t sum, size_t rows, size_t columns)
{
    int numbersElements = rows * columns;
    average = sum / numbersElements;
    return average;
}




int main()
{
    size_t rows, columns, sum; 

    cout << "Enter the number of rows of the matrix:";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns in the matrix:";
    cin >> columns;

    int** matrix = new int* [rows];
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        matrix[row] = new int[columns];
    }

    FillRandomNumbers(matrix, rows, columns);

    cout << "\n matrix:\n";
    Print(matrix, rows, columns);

    cout << "\nThe sum of all elements of the matrix: " 
         << Sum(matrix, rows, columns) << endl;

    float average;
    cout << "\nThe average of all elements of the matrix: "
        << Average(average, sum, rows, columns) << endl;
}
```

Comment: виртуальные функции обычно есть [в объявлении класса.](https://ravesli.com/urok-163-virtualnye-funktsii-i-polimorfizm/)

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка сразу проявляется компилятором предупреждениями :

```
mass2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mass2.cpp:50:15: warning: ‘sum’ may be used uninitialized in this
 function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 average = sum / numbersElements;
       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mass2.cpp:59:23: note: ‘sum’ was declared here
 size_t rows, columns, sum;
```

После вычисления суммы, вы результат никуда не сохраняете

```
cout << "\nThe sum of all elements of the matrix: " 
  << Sum(matrix, rows, columns) << endl;
```

И вычисление среднего значения приводит к неопределённому результату, так как в переменную `sum` :

```
size_t rows, columns, sum;
```

вы никакое значение не задаёте.

Поправляем так :

```
sum = Sum(matrix, rows, columns) ;
cout << "\nThe sum of all elements of the matrix: " 
  << sum << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Написать функцию, определяющую в двумерном массиве целых чисел :
Сумму всех элементов массива; Среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива;

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FillRandomNumbers
(int matrix[][50], const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
srand(time(0)); 

for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        matrix[row][column] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
}


void Print(int matrix[][50], const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    cout << endl;
    for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        cout << matrix[row][column] << " ";   
    }
}
}


int Sum(int matrix[][50], const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
int sum = 0; 
for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        sum += matrix[row][column];
    }
}
return sum; 
}

double  Average( int add[][50], size_t rows, size_t columns)
{
int numbersElements = rows * columns;

double sum = Sum(add, rows, columns);

return sum / numbersElements;;
}


int main()
{
const int rows = 50, columns = 50;
int ro, co;
cout << "Enter the number of rows of the matrix:";
cin >> ro;
cout << "Enter the number of columns in the matrix:";
cin >> co;

int matrix  [rows][columns];


FillRandomNumbers(matrix, ro, co);

cout << "\n matrix:\n";
Print(matrix, ro, co);

cout << "\nThe sum of all elements of the matrix: " 
     << Sum(matrix, ro, co) << endl;

float average;
cout << "\nThe average of all elements of the matrix: "
    << Average(matrix, ro, co) << endl;



}
```